# Best Practices for Client Management Beyond Online Marketplaces

Tags: clients, freelance

As a freelancer, I've been navigating projects both within and outside of online marketplaces. While marketplaces offer a structured environment for client management, I find it challenging to maintain efficiency and professionalism when dealing with clients outside of these platforms.

What are some recommended strategies or tools for effectively managing clients beyond online marketplaces? I'm particularly interested in insights on communication methods, project organization, invoicing, and payment processing, as well as fostering long-term professional relationships. Any experienced advice or practical tips would be invaluable. Thank you!

Comment: This is very broad. You might want to break this up into multiple questions that can be answered here.